# How can I set slick.js settings base on my windows size (Desktop, Tablet, Phone)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, slick.js

I have a bunch of custom of HTML divs. I store **3** of them in a div with class **slide**. Then, I use that slide class to call the **slick** function and apply the settings like this:

```
$('.slide').slick({

    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,

});
```

For those of you that don't know, here is [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

My whole UI at this point look like this:

[image]

They look fine when they're in full-screen, but as soon as I decrease the windows size, they look very poor. I'm thinking to set my slick settings base on my windows size. For example,

```
If window size = full OR 1080px {
$('.slide').slick({

        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,

    });

}

else if window size = medium or 720px {
$('.slide').slick({

        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,

    });


}else{


// This is for the phone

$('.slide').slick({

        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,

    });
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do achieve something like this?

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/va5qkycp/1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [official document](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), it can be pretty easy.

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```